# Any event to close the colorbox while it's loading?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Any event to close the jQuery colorbox while it's loading?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not very clear. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I'm loading some information into colorbox,while loading i should be able to close the colorbox.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a *function*, then `$.fn.colorbox.close()` will close the colorbox if it's shown, regardless of whether it is still loading. If you're talking about an *event*, you'll need to elaborate.

Comment: I'm loading some information into colorbox,while loading i should be able to close the colorbox. 
Once the content is loaded then $.fn.colorbox.close() will work, but while loading Is it possible to close?

Answer (score 0):

onLoad:function(){ parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();}

use this function on where you are opening the colorbox.